# Integral in different coordinate system

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to find $\iint_Dxye^yd(x,y)$, where $D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|1\le x\le3, 0\le y\le \ln(x)\}$.
To solve this, $D$ should me mapped to a rectangle, such that you can use Fubini's theorem and thus, reduce it all to simple integration on a rectangle. However, I can't think of a transformation $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$, such that for an $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ $\iint_Dxye^yd(x,y)=\iint_{g(\Omega)}xye^yd(x,y)$

So how to find $g$ and $\Omega$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried 
$$
(x, y) \mapsto (x, y \ln x) ?
$$

This takes the rectangle 
$$
1 \le x \le 3 \\
0 \le y \le 1
$$
to 
$$
1 \le x \le 3 \\
0 \le y \le \ln x .
$$